# How to compare consistency between clustering results and list of values with different levels in R?

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, cohens-kappa

I found similar subjects on the website but I may have missed the relation with my own question. I'v seen questions about comparison of clustering results, but here it's more about comparing two lists with different levels in R. Apologies if this is already discussed.

I'm currently doing a clustering analysis on some data (k-means, hierarchical thru heatmap but whatever). I want to check if my clustering ("Cluster group" column) is consistent with a list of values ("tropism" column) attached to my individuals. Thing is that this list of values, of course, doesn't have the same levels than my clustering results. I would like to make a kappa-fleiss consistency test on both variables (clustering results v.s. list of values). Here is a shortened version of my dataframe :

```
                Cluster group tropism    
JX308829.1 all  "1"           "digestif" 
NC_020890.1 all "1"           "digestif" 
KF954417.1 all  "1"           "peau"     
HM011544.1 all  "2"           "peau"      
MH844627.1 all  "2"           "peau"     
HQ696595.1 all  "2"           "rein"     
AB211390.1 all  "2"           "rein"     
AB301101.1 all  "2"           "rein"     
HM011559.1 all  "2"           "digestif" 
KY404016.1 all  "2"           "rein"      
KF444093.1 all  "3"           "cerveau"    
KJ725028.1 all  "3"           "peau"     
GU296408.1 all  "3"           "peau"     
EU711058.1 all  "3"           "syst_resp"
KC549591.1 all  "4"           "syst_resp"  
AB092581.1 all  "5"           "peau"     
AB127351.2 all  "5"           "digestif"
```

Problem is that, naturally, kappa-fleiss consistency score compare two lists with the same levels.

I tried to create an algorithm where each cluster level is renamed following the majority of values in it, but of course it seems a little bit "manipulating the data", and I have some equalities between and inside of groups, making it hard to select values for my cluster groups. I then have multiple questions:

1. Why couldn't I compare the consistency between two list of variables with different levels? It seems a little bit naive, but shouldn't consistency be measured between groups (like if "digestive" is correlated with "cluster group 1" or whatever)? Is there an option that I missed in the kappam.fleiss() function?
2. Is there a function, a test or whatever that I missed? I May apologize if so, but I tried to find something as powerful and significant as kappa-fleiss testing, without any success.
3. Do you think I should manipulate data as mentioned before? Is that acceptable, even if I have some parts that I must manipulate by hand?

Comment: You are comparing two partitions of the same set of objects without prior knowledge which group in one partition corresponds to which one in the other. 20+ indices to assess such similarity are known as _external clustering criteria_. One cluster solution is being compared either with another obtained solution or with some reference grouping.

Comment: You will find many threads here (under clustering tag) about those. Also, I recommend you to visit my web-page and download/read the description of !CLUAGREE macro in the zip called "Compare partitions". There you will find all the formulas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers that highlighted me a part of clustering analysis I wasn't aware of. I looked the different solutions to work on external clustering and found that purity / entropy measuring wasn't for me (same number of clusters than levels for my list of values). I'm now looking forward to precision / recall / F-metrics to validate the relation between my clusters and my preexisting values. I'm not really sure if that's necessary but could you please write your comments as answers ? I could then validate them ! Thanks again

Comment: Good luck to you. Cohen's or Fleiss kappa is not for you because they require you to know which group in one partition corresponds to which one in the other. Such measures are described in my macro !CLASAGREE.